# C++ - Why does the order of insertion-type affect Vector performance (GCC 4.81)

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, iteration, allocation

I have a puzzling problem.

Context is: dataset of unknown size which gets iterated over constantly but has minimal insertions after initialisation (speed at initialisation not a concern).
The data is sorted into ordered indexes of unknown numbers.

So I am using vectors but positioning the insertion of elements according to the index numbers.
The strange thing I've found is that the order of insertion *type* affects iteration performance.

Specifically I was dealing with a test scenario where I was adding three identical elements, with indexes 0, 1 and 2.

Now, depending on the order they are added to the vector, they will either be push_back'd or .insert'd, in order to create the correct linear order of numbers.

And I created a loop iterating over these and seeing how many loops I could accomplish in a given timeframe (10 seconds).

What I found was that if I added them in this order:
1, 2, 0

I got on-average 60 more loops than if I added them in this order:

2, 0, 1

and 30 more loops than this order:

0, 1, 2.

In each case the insertions are correctly sorted so that the order within the vector is 0, 1, 2. The only difference between them is the type of insertion required.

For 012, each insertion is a pushback.
For 201, the first is a pushback, second is an insertion at .begin() and third is an insertion before the iterator corresponding to '2'.
For 120, the first is a pushback, second is a pushback and the third is an insertion at .begin().

Why should the third case scenario be any more performant?
To re-iterate, there Is *No* Difference between the methods in terms of the order or type or quantity of data stored - in each case the resultant order of the vector is 0, 1, 2.

I tested this with GCC 4.8.1 both with and without -O2. The results were repeatable with minor fluctuations of 1-4 loops.
To be fair, the differences are still minor - we are talking 60 loops out of around 15000.

The only explanation I can think of is that the insertion type changes the allocation of the vector, possibly resulting in better, or worse, performance.

Comment: You've convoluted your question a little by listing the cases in one order and then discussing them in another.

Comment: push_back generally costs less than arbitrary insertion of an element in a std::vector. push_back is worst case linear time O(n) but in average constant amortized time O(1). Worst case scenario occurs when vector has to be re-sized and therefore all elements have to be copied in newly allocated memory. On the other hand inserting an element in vector is linear time, since you have to shift all the elements after it.

Comment: How did you time this, and what kind of elements are these? 15000 loops in 10 seconds sounds really slow.

Comment: If I understand correctly your performance question has nothing to do with insertion performance, and only to do with how quickly you can iterate over the vector once populated.  Correct?  And your experiments show a difference of 30-60 iterations out of 15000?  That's not significant unless you can reproduce it dozens of times, alternating between versions.  Even then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ ooga - the order of insertion is different to the order of sorted data.

@Zwinck - You are correct, but it is repeatable as noted, and whether it matters depends on your scenario. The difference is 60 +/- four in one situation, 30 +/- 4 in another. I'm more personally interested in How this is possible, not whether it's useful.

@ user2357112 - the elements in question are vectors of class instances of a fixed size. Timed with SDL's built-in millisecond timer functions.

@ Dimitrios, it's not a question of insertion time but iteration time.

Comment: Might want to edit the question to give it a bit more clarity - I think it's not entirely clear that you are asking about iteration time instead of insertion time.

Comment: I can't understand where the loops fit in. What are you measuring?

Answer (score 0):

Let's count number of copies that will be done in each case (assuming initial vector is empty and resulting vector has {0,1,2} elements):

012 -> 3 copies: push_back 3 times

120 -> 5 copies:

- push_back(1) : 1 copy
- push_back(2) : 1 copy
- insert(0) : 2 copies to shift existing elements and 1 copy to insert "0"

201 -> 5 copies:

- push_back(2) : 1 copy
- insert(0) : 1 copy to shift "2" and 1 copy to insert "0"
- insert(1) : 1 copy to shift "2" and 1 copy to insert "1"

So if it's only about copying then 120 and 201 should not be different, but you also should consider the time to find position. I guess you are using binary search to find insertion position and it looks like it works better in 120 case. Or maybe there is some optimization - 120 looks easier to predict.